# Алгоритм поиска пути A*

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализировать алгоритм поиска пути А*. Я новичок в программировании и плохо в этом разбираюсь.

Прочитал статью Алгоритм A* для новичков (ну она наиболее понятна) + нашел какой-то исходник на Java.

Интуитивно алгоритм понятен. На каждом кроке для каждой точки с открытого списка считаем стоимость F = G + H (как их посчитать мне понятно) и т.п.

Непонятно, как сделать все это програмно на уровне "новичка".

Например, мне непонятно, как работать со списками, как проверять точки и как определить родительскую точку для текущей точки.

Наверно нужен какой- то класс типа DOT с свойствами x,y,F,G,H,parent который умеет считать стоимости F,G,H и сохранять родителя. Но если так, то создавать сразу объекты для каждой точки карты или как.

В качестве списков думал использовать <vector>.

Примеры исходников, которые я нашел в сети малопонятны.

Answer (score 2):

1. https://web.archive.org/web/20171010173351/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial_rus.htm
2. Может лучше познакомиться с азами, а потом уже браться за столь непростой алгоритм?
3. Программировать будете на C++? Заключил по упоминанию шаблонного класса . Ну, что ж - не самый плохой выбор.

> Наверно нужен какой- то класс типа DOT с свойствами x,y,F,G,H,parent который умеет считать стоимости F,G,H и сохранять родителя.

Класс или структура нужна. А вот считать F,G,H можно вручную. Родителя сохраняете, очевидно, в момент добавления точки к списку. При этом можно или указывать индекс родителя в списке, или координаты, или просто указатель на него давать (очевидно, что в списке точек родитель всегда найдется). Но никто не мешает использовать ООП-подход. Например, сделать конструктор элемента, который будет принимать указанные Вами параметры. А часть параметров - рассчитывать самостоятельно.

> Примеры исходников, которые я нашел в сети малопонятны.

Приведите ссылку, попробуем разобраться. Что конкретно было непонятно?

Answer (score 2):

Можете почитать еще вот [здесь](http://pmg.org.ru/ai/stout.htm). - Рассматриваются различные алгоритмы поиска пути, их достоинства и недостатки в различных случаях игровых окружений. Помимо поиска пути ресурс [Программирование Магических Игр](http://pmg.org.ru/) содержит и другую информацию по программированию игр...

Answer (score 0):

Да, класс ячейки понадобится с указанными вами полями. Создавать новые объекты этого класса стоит при рассмотрении соседей ячейки с наименьшей f из открытого списка. Например, если ячейка квадрат, то берём ячейку с наименьшей стоимостью из открытого списка, создаём 3 новых ячейки с координатами её соседей (три, так как четвёртый сосед наверно будет родителем из закрытого списка), рассчитываем для них все параметры и кладём в отрытый список. Ни в коем случае не стоит создавать сразу все ячейки для карты, так как многие наверно останутся невостребованными. И для открытого списка я бы посоветовал что-то вроде priorityQueue (лучше, если у этого контейнера был бы ещё возврат индекса по элементу).